# Scala : take abtract class as an object and can change when declare in normal class

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract-class

For example I have this code :

```
abstract class A {
  def functionA() {
    val a : A = null; // take null just for temporary, because I cannot think what should to put here
    a.functionB
  }

  def functionB() {
      print("hello")
  }
}

class C extends A{
}

object Main extends App {
  val c : C = new C()
  c.functionB // print hello
  c.functionA // ERROR
}
```

at `functionA`, I want declare a object in case : if the current class is C, a will have type C. if the current class is D, a will have type D. Because I cannot do :

```
val a : A = new A // because A is abstract
```

In Java, I can do this easily, but I cannot do like that in Scala. Please help me this.

Thanks :)

Comment: How would you do this in Java?

Comment: It's some tangled logic you're adopting. A sure sign to reconsider the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want declare a object in case : if the current class is C, a will
>   have type C. if the current class is D, a will have type D

If I understand correctly, you are talking about plain inheritance polymorphism. You can assign `this` reference to `a` value in your case, or just use it directly:

```
abstract class A {
  def functionA {
    this.functionB
  }

  def functionB {
    print("hello")
  }
}

class C extends A{
}

object Main extends App {
  val c : C = new C()
  c.functionB
  c.functionA
}
```

In this case there will be no `NullPointerException`.

However, if you really want to create *new* object of the real type inside base class, you should use inheritance polymorphism in other way (I think this is somewhat simpler than whan @brunoconde suggested, but the idea is very similar; I don't think that generics are really needed here):

```
abstract class A {
  def functionA {
    val a : A = create()
    a.functionB
  }

  def functionB {
    print("hello")
  }

  def create(): A
}

class C extends A {
  override def create() = new C
}
```

This is what I'd do in Java if I had to. You have to override `create()` method in every child class though. I doubt that it is possible to do this without overriding while not resorting to reflection.